# Deleting and Renaming file java

Tags: java

I am trying to delete and rename a file however the delete() and rename() function does not work. I can't seem to find the bug in the code as it should run properly by logic (i think). Can anyone tell me why it can't delete a fill. this code works except deleting old txt and renaming temp.txt to old file.

```
public Boolean deleteItem(String item){
    try{
        // creating and opening file
        File f = new File("temp.txt");
        f.delete(); // to delete existing data inside file;
        File old = new File(file);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("temp.txt"), true);

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(old);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;

        // creating temporary item object
        String[] strArr;

        //searching for data inside the file
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null){
            strArr = s.split("\\'");                
            if (!strArr[0].equals(item)){
                writer.append(s + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        }

        //rename old file to file.txt

        old.delete();
        boolean successful = f.renameTo(new File(file));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        fr.close();
        reader.close();

        return successful;
    }
    catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be deleting the file not the content, see Oracle documentation on [File.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#delete()). Also, what is in the variable called `file`?

Comment: Don't use the old `java,io.File`. It is notorious for its lax error handling and useless error messages. Use the "newer" NIO.2 `java.nio.file.Path` and the `java.nio.file.Files` methods that were added in Java 7.

Comment: The code you posted in your question does not compile because it is missing the declaration of variable `file`. From the _javadoc_ of method [delete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) in class `java.io.File`, the method _Deletes the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname._ If you want to delete all the contents of the file, but not delete the file, simply open it for writing.

Comment: yes. first to be able renew all data in file, I will need to check if the file exist as I am appending context to it, delete if found and recreate a new file with the same filename temp.txt. then copy contents from old file which does not match the parameter, delete old file and rename temp file to old one.@Scratte

Comment: @Abra . variable file is a global variable which is also a parameter of constructor

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems a little tangled. Here's what I think it looks like.

You delete file.txt
You create a new file.txt and copy 'file' into it
You delete 'file'
You rename file.txt to 'file'
You close input and output files

My guess would be that your operating system (unspecified) is preventing deletes and renames of open files. Move the closing to before the delete/rename.  And check the return from those functions.

Aside: as a minor improvement to readability, you don't need to keep calling 'new File(xxx)' with the same xxx.  A File is just a representation of the name of the file.  Do it once.  And 'File tempFile = new File("file.txt")' would be easier to follow than calling it 'f'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the old [`java.io.File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html). It is notorious for its lax error handling and useless error messages. Use the "newer" NIO.2 [`java.nio.file.Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and the [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) methods that were *added in Java 7*.

E.g. the `file.delete()` method returns `false` if the file was not deleted. No exception is thrown, so you'll never know why, and since you don't even check the return value, you don't know that it didn't delete the file either.

The file isn't deleted because you still have it open. Close the files before attempting to delete+rename, and do it using **try-with-resources**, also *added in Java 7*.

Your code should be the following, through capturing exceptions and turning them into a `boolean` return value is error-prone (see issue with `file.delete()`).

```
public boolean deleteItem(String item){
    try {
        // creating and opening file
        Path tempFile = Paths.get("temp.txt");
        Files.deleteIfExists(tempFile); // Throws exception if delete failed

        Path oldFile = Paths.get(file);
        try ( BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile);
              BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(oldFile); ) {

            //searching for data inside the file
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                String[] strArr = line.split("\\'");
                if (! strArr[0].equals(item)){
                    writer.append(line + System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }

        } // Files are flushed and closed here

        // replace file with temp file
        Files.delete(oldFile); // Throws exception if delete failed
        Files.move(tempFile, oldFile); // Throws exception if rename failed

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to remove selected lines from a text file.
The following code uses the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)<sup>1</sup>. It filters out all the unwanted lines and writes the lines that you do want to a temporary file. Then it renames the temporary file to your original file, thus effectively removing the unwanted lines from the original file. Note that I am assuming that your "global" variable `file` is a string.

```java
/* Following imports required.
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
*/
Path path = Paths.get(file);
final PrintWriter[] pws = new PrintWriter[1];
try {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".txt");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    pws[0] = new PrintWriter(tempFile);
    Files.lines(path)
         .filter(l -> !item.equals(l.split("'")[0]))
         .forEach(l -> pws[0].println(l));
    pws[0].flush();
    pws[0].close();
    Files.move(tempFile.toPath(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
catch (IOException xIo) {
    xIo.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if (pws[0] != null) {
        pws[0].close();
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Stream API was introduced in Java 8